# Using require to load multiple functions

Tags: javascript, browserify

I'm designing an art tool for a project and I've created a set of types of properties that brush could have. Things such as an number for the size of the brush, dropdowns, booleans, images, etc. Each of these has a few methods associated with them and they're stored in one file. The file structure is basically

```
var property1 = {
    ...
}

var property2 = {
    ...
}

....
modules.exports = property1,property2;
```

I'm now working on creating a variety of default brushes so I have a prototype and a bunch of files containing the types of brushes I want to use. Since I'm trying to keep only one brush per file, I end up importing all of the files at the top of each file in the following way:

```
var properties = require('./pathtofile');
var property1 = properties.property1;
var propert2 = properties.property2;
...
```

I'm trying to cut down on having lengthy lines with a lot of dots moving through hierarchy in them. Is there a better way to import multiple objects from another file either using browserify or another tool? I don't want these to be available globally but since there are a lot of properties it seems like a ton of repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

Is the object destructuring syntax the one you are looking for?

```
const { property1 , property2 } = require('./pathtofile')
```

Comment: That works. I was hoping for something that deconstructed the object without needing to explicitly rewrite each property name but this is definitely more concise than before.